# Como pego este valor

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite,  preciso de um auxilio com o código abaixo.

Este código já funciona para o que preciso. Geolocalização para exibir os usuários mais próximos, mas como eu pego o valor da distancia???

```
$user = $con->query("SELECT user_nome, user_user, user_idade, user_img, 
(6371 * acos(
cos( radians($lat) )
* cos( radians( user_latitude ) )
* cos( radians( user_longitude ) - radians($long) )
+ sin( radians($lat) )
* sin( radians( user_latitude ) ) 
)
) AS distancia
FROM usuarios
HAVING distancia < 400
ORDER BY distancia ASC LIMIT 50", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Essa distancia não esta no meu banco nem em variável.. 
Queria mostrar por exemplo numa tabela:
user_nome e a distancia

Obrigado

Comment: Ao fazer isso que você está fazendo, o campo `distancia` é automaticamente criado no array associativo que possui os resultados da sua query. Basta iterar usando um foreach, por exemplo: `foreach ($user as $row) { echo $row['distancia'] } `.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser alterar a consulta SQL é fácil pegar as colunas que pretende:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
                SELECT      user_nome
                        ,   user_user
                        ,   user_idade
                        ,   user_img
                        ,   (6371 * acos(cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(user_latitude)) * cos(radians(user_longitude) - radians($long)) + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(user_latitude)))) AS distancia
                FROM        usuarios
            ) U
WHERE       U.distancia < 400
ORDER BY    U.distancia
LIMIT       50
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado...

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta lhe foi útil dê um UP, e se estiver correta marque-a como tal!

Answer (score 0):

Esse código que pus tinha funcionado e agora não funciona nada.. não sei o que eu tinha feito ou se ele apenas leu alguma informação anterior.. enfim.. fiz isso e não retorna nada.. o que estou fazendo errado?
Criei uma tabela apenas para testar e coloquei estas informações q viriam do bd..

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Lat</td>
<td>Long</td>
<td>Nome</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>-25.4921949</td>
<td>-49.2676986</td>
<td>Hauer 001</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>-25.53517</td>
<td>-49.2911306</td>
<td>Pinheirinho 001</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>-25.5015146</td>
<td>-49.2437735</td>
<td>Boqueirao 001</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```html
  require "config/conexao.php";
//estes números seriam do ponto inicial
$lat = "-25.4921949";
$long = "-49.2676986";
$user = $con->query("SELECT      *
FROM        (
                SELECT      user_nome
                        ,   user_user
                        ,   user_idade
                        ,   user_img
                        ,   (6371 * acos(cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(user_latitude)) * cos(radians(user_longitude) - radians($long)) + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(user_latitude)))) AS distancia
                FROM        usuarios
            ) U
WHERE       U.distancia < 1000
ORDER BY    U.distancia
LIMIT       50", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($user as $row) {
  echo $row['distancia'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desculpa pessoal.. postei um problema agora a pouco mas encontrei o q precisava em outro fórum.. deu certo para o que eu queria e até melhor.. vou postar aqui caso alguém precise...
Geolocalização.. pegará a cidade, estado e país do usuário.. dai vc faz o restante.. eu inclui no formulário de cadastro...
Obrigado as respostas daqui...
OBS: não consegui formatar o código aqui separando o java do html.. dava erro e sou noob aqui

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Geolocation</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="localizacao" >

            <input id="cidade" value="">
            <input id="estado" value="">
            <input id="pais" value="">

            <button   type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Salvar</button>
        </form>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

            var lati = '';
            var long = '';
            var cidade = '';
            var estado = '';
            var pais = '';
            var dadosajax = '';

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (posicao) {
                var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=" + posicao.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + posicao.coords.longitude + "&format=json&json_callback=preencherDados";

                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = url;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
                lati = posicao.coords.latitude;
                long = posicao.coords.longitude;

            });

            function preencherDados(dados) {
                cidade = dados.address.city;
                estado = dados.address.state;
                pais = dados.address.country;



                //alert('cordenadas:' + lati + ',' + long + '    Lugar:' + cidade + ',' + estado + ',' + pais);
                

                document.getElementById('cidade').value = cidade;
                document.getElementById('estado').value = estado;
                document.getElementById('pais').value = pais;


                dadosajax = {'cidade':cidade, 'estado':estado, 'pais':pais};
                
                $("#localizacao").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert(dadosajax);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "teste6.php",
                        data: dadosajax

                    });
                });




            }
            ;
        </script>
        </body>
            </html>
```